# Как работает BufferedReader?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, поток-ввода

Есть код:

```
import java.io.*;

class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
                BufferedReader qq = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in), 1);
                int x = qq.read();
                int y = System.in.read();
        }
}
```

Я рассчитываю, что размер буфера будет равен 1. То есть когда программа попросит ввести данные и я введу например `qwer`, а потом нажму *enter*, буква *q* будет прочитана и её код запишется в `x`. После этого, так как это буферизованный поток, символы будут помещены в буфер, но так как я назначил его размер равным одному, то туда будет помещен лишь один символ - *w*. Следовательно в потоке остаётся еще 3 символа (*e*, *r* и *enter*) и код первого из них будет помещен в `y`.

Но к удивлению, сколько бы символов я не вводил программа каждый раз просит меня ввести значения для переменной `y`. Почему? Как это работает?

Comment: Это магия StreamDecoder-а внутри InputStreamReader. Если его просят считать 1 байт, то он запрашивает 2. А в запросе 2 байт в методе `implRead` фигурирует `readBytes`, которому всё равно на количество запрошенного, если оно меньше 8192 :)

Comment: @kami а что такое это StreamDecoder ? Почему то про него в гугле нету информации

Comment: А я про него не гуглил, а по шагам прошелся по внутренностям qq.read(). Из BufferedReader выполнение уходит в InputStreamReader, а в нём - в StreamDecoder. Словом, BufferedReader ни при чём, он молодец и действительно читает 1 байт. Ну а что происходит в том, над чем он выступает оберткой - это уже не его зона ответственности.

Comment: @kami я извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, просто я новичок. А "прошелся по внутренностям" означает воспользовался отладчиком ?)

Comment: Да, именно отладчиком, благо IDE более чем способна генерировать исходники из скомпилированных файлов. Не знаю, как оформить результаты отладки ответом, чтобы это было понятно именно для начинания. Не последовательность же вызовов прикладывать, тем более что в зависимости от версии Java она может несколько отличаться.

Comment: ознакомьтесь с циклом лекций  https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.1.php
а для углубленных знаний можно посмотреть лекции про `IO` ивана головоча на ютубе

Comment: @kami да действительно, у меня получается добиться желаемого результата, если ввести больше, чем 8192 символов. Тогда в неком `StreamDecoder`-е заполняется буфер и оставшиеся символы остаются в потоке. Первый из оставшихся помещается в переменную `y`

Comment: @kami Но такой результат, только если я выполняю код в ide (в моём случае intellij на windows). Если я например выполняю этот же код в Linux консоли, то по какой-то причине, в не зависимости от количества введенных символов, даже если их будет ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО, программа всё равно просит меня ввести данные в `y`. Как будто там бесконечный буфер. С чем это связано? Как это работает ?

Comment: Вам явно надо самому влезть в отладку в эти методы :) На линуксе видимо другая реализация / другие значения у ByteBuffer, который внутри StreamDecoder-а. Вот вам для затравки последовательность вызовов (в скобках - номера строк, соответствуют Java 17.0.3): BufferedReader.read(183)->BufferedReader.fill(162)->InputStreamReader.read(177)->StreamDecoder.read(181)->StreamDecoder.read0(137)->StreamDecoder.read(188)->StreamDecoder.implRead(313)->StreamDecoder.readBytes(270)

Comment: @kami получается, если нас устраивает буфер размером 8192 и нам не нужны методы из `BufferedReader` нет никакого смысла использовать `BufferedReader`, так как `InputStreamReader` тоже буферизирует информацию и будет работать с такой же эффективностью. Верно ?